# Dynamically Appending Elements to jQuery Mobile ListView

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I want to dynamically append data received via an url in JSOn format to my listview. But i can't figure out how it works.

The mobile website retrieve the object in the following format:

```
[
    {"id":1, "start":"2011-10-29T13:15:00.000+10:00", "end":"2011-10-29T14:15:00.000+10:00", "title":"Meeting"}
]
```

In the .html i have one listview and a function, where i try to append the received data. I show only the body.

```
<body>
       <div>   
            <ul id="listview">
                <script>$.getJSON("url",
                function(data){
                    $.each(data, function(i,data){
                        i.title.appendTo("#listview");
                    });});</script> 
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

Probably it's very easy, but i'm new to web programming and i can't figure out how that i should append the retrieved data.

Can anyone please help me out ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
//make AJAX call to url
$.getJSON("url", function(data){

    //declare a variable with which to build our output (it's best to buffer output and only do one append at the end since DOM manipulation is CPU expensive)
    var output = '';

    //iterate through the data (we could also get rid of the jQuery here by using `for (key in data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value){

        //add each value to the output buffer (we also have access to the other properties of this object: id, start, and end)
        output += '<li>' + value.title + '</li>';
    });

    //now append the buffered output to the listview and either refresh the listview or create it (meaning have jQuery Mobile style the list)
    $('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');//or if the listview has yet to be initialized, use `.trigger('create');` instead of `.listview('refresh');`
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution (there is also an example of using `for(){}` instead of `$.each()`): http://jsfiddle.net/VqULm/

Answer (score 1):

I'm appending like this..Its working for appending..
It may be helpful for you or others :)

```
          $.each(data.values, function(key, value) {

          $('#activity_contacts').append('<li id="activity_contacts" data-id="' + value.contact_id + '">' + value.display_name + '</li>');
          $("#activity_contacts").listview("refresh");


          });
```

My entire autocomplete is like this:

```
    function contactSearchForActivities (q) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg( 'Searching' );
    $().crmAPI ('Contact','get',
      {'version' :'3', 'activity_sort_name': q, 'return' : 'display_name' },
      {
        ajaxURL: crmajaxURL,
        success:function (data){
          if (data.count == 0) {
            cmd = null;
          }
          else {
            cmd = "refresh";
            $('#activity_contacts').show();
            $('#activity_contacts').empty();
          }
          //console.log(data);

          //loop to go through the values in order to display them in a li as a list


          $.each(data.values, function(key, value) {

          $('#activity_contacts').append('<li id="' + value.contact_id + '" title = "' + value.display_name +'">' + value.display_name + '</li>');

   }); 

   $("#activity_contacts li").click(function() {

   $('#activity_sort_name').val(this.title);
   $('#activity_hidden_id').val(this.id);
           $("#activity_contacts").empty();
   });

          $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg( );
          $('#activity_contacts').listview(cmd);
        }
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you might be encountering is that the JSON being returned is an object *wrapped in an array*. To parse you will have to iterate through the array first:

```
for( var x = 0; x < data.length; x++ ) {
 var i = data[ x ];
 i.title.appendTo("#listview");
}
```

Comment: I believe that was an issue, but Unfortunately didn't solve everything. It must have another issue. Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please refresh the listview after appeding or removing.
Unless you do refresh nothing can be seen.

```
$('#listview').append(output).listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to recreate a listview then you'll need to .trigger(create) and .listview(refresh) the list. The issue is explained at http://liljosh.com/jquery-mobile-dynamicly-appending-to-listview-via-ajax-issue/

Comment: Hi Josh! Please take a moment to read over [so] policies regarding [self promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). In addition, there are many posts talking about the same issue on meta. Here is one of them - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: From what I can see in your profile, you've been self-promoting **quite a lot**.